# Full-featured date and time library

Tags: python, c, datetime

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a good date and time library that has correctly-implemented features like the following:

- **Microsecond resolution**
- **Daylight savings**

  - *Example:* it knows that 2:30am did not exist in the US on 8 March 2009 for timezones that respect daylight savings.
  - I should be able to specify a timezone like "US/Eastern" and it should be smart enough to know whether a given timestamp should correspond to EST or EDT.
- **Custom date ranges**

  - The ability to create specialized business calendars that skip over weekends and holidays.
- **Custom time ranges**

  - The ability to define business hours so that times requested outside the business hours can be rounded up or down to the next or previous valid hour.
- **Arithmetic**

  - Be able to add and subtract integer amounts of all units (years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes, ...).  Note that adding something like 0.5 days isn't well-defined because it could mean 12 hours or it could mean half the duration of a day (which isn't 24 hours on daylight savings changes).
- **Natural boundary alignment**

  - Given a timestamp, I'd like be able to do things like round down to the nearest decade, year, month, week, ..., quarter hour, hour, etc.

I'm currently using Python, though I'm happy to have a solution in another language like perl, C, or C++.

I've found that the built-in Python libraries lack sophistication with their daylight savings logic and there isn't an obvious way (to me) to set up things like custom time ranges.

Comment: "I should be able to specify a timezone like "US/Eastern" and it should be smart enough to know whether a given timestamp should correspond to EST or EDT" -- I don't think that's possible unless you give a more specific location. Indiana only recently started doing DST, and Arizona and Hawaii still don't.

Comment: In case time zones aren't exploding your head yet, a couple fun ones: Argentina observes daylight savings per-province; each province decides for itself when DST begins and ends.  India has a time zone offset of +5:30, making "rounding to the nearest hour" a lot of fun.  Nepal is +5:45, making pretty much everything a lot of fun.

Comment: Steven: "US/Eastern" implies that EDT is used.  If you're in Indiana, you're in US/Indiana-Starke, not US/Eastern.  Similarly, if you're in a part of Arizona that doesn't follow DST, you're in US/Arizona (some parts of the state do).

Answer (score 11):

Python's standard library's `datetime` module is deliberately limited to non-controversial aspects that aren't changing all the time by legislative fiat -- that's why it deliberately excludes direct support for timezones, DST, fuzzy parsing and ill-defined arithmetic (such as "one month later"...) and the like. On top of it, [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) for many kinds of manipulations, and [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) for timezones (including DST issues), add most of what you're asking for, though not *extremely* explosive things like "holidays" which vary so wildly not just across political jurisdictions but even across employers within a simgle jurisdiction (e.g. in the US some employers consider "Columbus Day" a holiday, but many don't -- and some, with offices in many locations, have it as a holiday on some locations but not in others; given this utter, total chaos, to expect to find a general-purpose library that somehow magically makes sense of the chaos is pretty weird).

Comment: +1: and if you really need, you could handle holiday calendars with dateutil module. Basically you need to configure rruleset, which will include rules for each holiday. then you can combine those rules with you base calendar etc. Of course you have to configure all by your self, but this can be done at least just once and then used in your library for all the company/project

Comment: "There's complexity here so let's ignore it and let the user deal with the mess". Thanks python.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) and possibly [mx.DateTime](http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxDateTime/) packages.

Answer (score 6):

Saw this the other day, I havn't used it myself... looks promising. http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/

Comment: Thank you - I kept thinking "somebody must have fixed this for me by now, right?" Glad to see an effort to bring datetime sanity to python

Answer (score 4):

> I should be able to specify a timezone
>   like "US/Eastern" and it should be
>   smart enough to know whether a given
>   timestamp should correspond to EST or
>   EDT.

This part isn't always possible - in the same way that 2:30am doesn't exist for one day of the year (in timezones with daylight saving that switches at 2:00am), 2:30am exists *twice* for another day - once in EDT and then an hour later in EST.  If you pass that date/time to the library, how does it know which of the two times you're talking about?

Comment: I'd like it to do something smart with 2:30am in each case.  From what I've found in the pytz library, there isn't a public way to ask it if a timestamp is non-existent or ambiguous.  As long as the library has a clear way of providing this information, I'm happy.

Answer (score 2):

Although the book is over ten years old, I would strongly recommend reading [**Standard C Date/Time Library: Programming the World's Calendars and Clocks**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0879304960) by Lance Latham. This is one of those books that you will pick back up from time to time in amazement that it got written at all. The author goes into more detail than you want about calenders and time keeping systems, and along the way develops the source code to a library (written in C) to handle all of the calculations.

Amazingly, it seems to be still in print...

Comment: The fact that some reviewers easily found an error in a basic routine (Julian to Gregorian) makes me a bit skeptical to use it as an authoritative reference.

Comment: In the nearly nine years since I wrote this answer, this book does seem to have fallen out of print somewhere along the way. It also has some difficulties with code licenses, likely caused by collision between a venerable and stodgy publisher (CRC Press) and the modern world of freer licensing. I stand by my assertion that it is an interesting read, however. Date and time are complicated problems because they stand on a border between human conventions and scientific truth. And the rules change with both time and place.

Answer (score 1):

I just released a Python library called Fleming (https://github.com/ambitioninc/fleming), and it appears to solve two of your problems with sophistication in regards to Daylight Savings Time.

Problem 1, Arithmetic - Fleming has an add_timedelta function that takes a timedelta (from Python's datetime module) or a relativedelta from python-dateutil and adds it to a datetime object. The add_timedelta function handles the case when the datetime object crosses a DST boundary. Check out https://github.com/ambitioninc/fleming#add_timedelta for a complete explanation and examples. Here is a short example:

```
import fleming
import datetime
import timedelta

dt = fleming.add_timedelta(dt, datetime.timedelta(weeks=2, days=1))
print dt
2013-03-29 20:00:00-04:00
# Do timedelta arithmetic such that it starts in DST and crosses over into no DST.
# Note that the hours stay in tact and the timezone changes
dt = fleming.add_timedelta(dt, datetime.timedelta(weeks=-4))
print dt
2013-03-01 20:00:00-05:00
```

Problem 2, Natural Boundary Alignment - Fleming has a floor function that can take an arbitrary alignment. Let's say your time was datetime(2013, 2, 3) and you gave it a floor interval of month=3. This means it will round to the nearest trimonth (quarter). You could similarly specify nearest decade by using year=10 in the arguments. Check out (https://github.com/ambitioninc/fleming#floordt-within_tznone-yearnone-monthnone-weeknone-daynone-hournone-minutenone-secondnone-microsecondnone) for complete examples and illustrations. Here is a quick one:

```
import fleming
import datetime

# Get the starting of a quarter by using month=3
print fleming.floor(datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 4), month=3)
2013-01-01 00:00:00
```