# Determining a timezone in Python

Tags: python, timezone

Given a local timestamp and a UTC timestamp, is it possible to determine the timezone and whether DST is in effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your "UTC timestamp" is a float (int would suffice) of "seconds from the epoch", and your "local timestamp" is some weird version of it shifted into your local time coordinates (there is no "epoch" except the UTC one), module [time](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) in the standard Python library suffices.

As these docs show, given "seconds from the epoch", `gmtime` translates that into a 9-items tuple in UTC, `localtime` into a 9-items tuple in local time; to go the other way around, `calendar.timegm` (UTC 9-items tuple to UTC timestamp) and `mktime` (local time 9-items tuple to UTC timestamp).  You'll note there's no such thing as a "local timestamp" (only local time 9-items tuples aka `struct_time` instances), simply because no such concept exists.

But, if I understand correctly what you mean by "local timestamp", then translating it to a struct time "as if" it was a real timestamp, and then back into local time, will give the offset you seek (in seconds).  As for DST, a bit telling whether it's on is the 9th item of the tuples we've been mentioning.

For example, using the "local timestamp" only:

```
>>> loct
1282453595
>>> time.mktime(time.gmtime(loct)) - loct
28800.0
>>> _ / 3600
8.0
>>>
```

This says I'm 8 hours west of UTC.  And:

```
>>> time.localtime(loct)[-1]
1
```

this says that it *is* with DST in effect.

Comment: Here was the problem: I have a UTC timestamp which represents 00:00:00 on an arbitrary date at an arbitrary timezone. I know what that arbitrary date is, but I do not know the timezone. If I convert the timestamp into a datetime object, I can use the hour value to determine the timezone, but the problem is DST. If DST is in effect, the timezone would be shifted by one. However, I'm sure that the timezone will be one in the US. Anyhow, I found a solution to the problem (albeit not a clean one, it'll suffice.) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at 
   http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime
for built-in support for dates, times, and timezones.

If you need a more powerful library, peek at the suggestions here: [Full-featured date and time library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442264/full-featured-date-and-time-library)